# How can I deal with a full striped volume?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ntfs, software-raid, hard-drive

I created a striped logical volume in Windows 7 x86 that is across 3 x 2TB drives. It's almost completely full, and I smacked my forehead when I realized today that you apparently cannot add drives to a striped volume. I do not have the budget to buy more drives at the moment and I cannot lose this data.

Is there a way to convert the striped volume to spanned?
Is there indeed a way to add drives to a striped volume that I'm not aware of?
Is there some other solution that I'm missing that doesn't involve wiping the partitions or buying more drives?

Comment: No you can't convert a Windows partition from striped to spanned without losing data. Back up your data. The next step is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember having an issue like this.  I *believe* with some certainty that I added spanned volume to an already existing (windows) striped volume.

edit:  to clarify, I believe I created a new spanned volume using the striped volume and the new volume.

Comment: In windows 7? No you can't